# Не получается создать миграцию "dotnet ef migrations add"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2

"dotnet ef migrations add" выдает ошибку.

Первая часть трассировки стека:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'IdentityDB' on server 'MAIN-PC-DEVS\SQLEXPRESS_0'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "IdentityDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MAIN-PC-DEVS\DEVS'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Видно, что EF Core не может подключиться к sql server'у, но не понимаю почему логин не валидный.
Чего я еще не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

PC:

- Windows 10
- sql server express 2019
- Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 3.1.8

[Файл](https://yadi.sk/d/qJ3fbMKackYHbA) с полной трассировкой

Comment: connection string : "Server=MAIN-PC-DEVS\\SQLEXPRESS_0;Database=IdentityDB;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

Comment: В Вашей строке подключения нет User ID и Password. Может проблема в этом?

Comment: @РустамАлиев, User ID и Password необязательны, у меня стоит авторизация через Windows. Данный проект у меня уже был в рабочем состоянии, но когда перешел на Win 10, скопировав проект, уже не работает, а так же есть еще проект, там всё так же считай, и всё работает нормально, а в конкретном случае, понятие не имею, что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНО!
Видимо для меня это было не совсем очевидно, как я понял "dotnet ef" взаимодействуя с проектом, запускает ,некоторый или весь, код в проекте.

ОТВЕТ:
В классе контекста у меня был определен метод, по созданию в БД учётной записи Админа.
И данный метод вызывался в Startup.Configure(), который обращался к еще несозданной БД, закомментировав его, я решил свою проблему.